# what happens when you define a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, tkinter

I found a beautiful script for making a snipp from actual window here on Stackoverflow and I'd love to use it in the personal application that I'm creating. But I think I'm missing something big here and I don't understand why it's not working.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui

import datetime

class Application():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.rect = None
        self.x = self.y = 0
        self.start_x = None
        self.start_y = None
        self.curX = None
        self.curY = None

        # root.configure(background = 'red')
        # root.attributes("-transparentcolor","red")

        root.attributes("-transparent", "blue")
        root.geometry('400x50+200+200')  # set new geometry
        root.title('Lil Snippy')
        self.menu_frame = Frame(master, bg="blue")
        self.menu_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.buttonBar = Frame(self.menu_frame,bg="")
        self.buttonBar.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=YES)

        self.snipButton = Button(self.buttonBar, width=3, command=self.createScreenCanvas, background="green")
        self.snipButton.pack(expand=YES)

        self.master_screen = Toplevel(root)
        self.master_screen.withdraw()
        self.master_screen.attributes("-transparent", "blue")
        self.picture_frame = Frame(self.master_screen, background = "blue")
        self.picture_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    def takeBoundedScreenShot(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        x = datetime.datetime.now()
        fileName = x.strftime("%f")
        im.save("snips/" + fileName + ".png")

    def createScreenCanvas(self):
        self.master_screen.deiconify()
        root.withdraw()

        self.screenCanvas = Canvas(self.picture_frame, cursor="cross", bg="grey11")
        self.screenCanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.screenCanvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_button_press)
        self.screenCanvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
        self.screenCanvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_button_release)

        self.master_screen.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.master_screen.attributes('-alpha', .3)
        self.master_screen.lift()
        self.master_screen.attributes("-topmost", True)

    def on_button_release(self, event):
        self.recPosition()

        if self.start_x <= self.curX and self.start_y <= self.curY:
            print("right down")
            self.takeBoundedScreenShot(self.start_x, self.start_y, self.curX - self.start_x, self.curY - self.start_y)

        elif self.start_x >= self.curX and self.start_y <= self.curY:
            print("left down")
            self.takeBoundedScreenShot(self.curX, self.start_y, self.start_x - self.curX, self.curY - self.start_y)

        elif self.start_x <= self.curX and self.start_y >= self.curY:
            print("right up")
            self.takeBoundedScreenShot(self.start_x, self.curY, self.curX - self.start_x, self.start_y - self.curY)

        elif self.start_x >= self.curX and self.start_y >= self.curY:
            print("left up")
            self.takeBoundedScreenShot(self.curX, self.curY, self.start_x - self.curX, self.start_y - self.curY)

        self.exitScreenshotMode()
        return event

    def exitScreenshotMode(self):
        print("Screenshot mode exited")
        self.screenCanvas.destroy()
        self.master_screen.withdraw()
        root.deiconify()

    def exit_application(self):
        print("Application exit")
        root.quit()

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        # save mouse drag start position
        self.start_x = self.screenCanvas.canvasx(event.x)
        self.start_y = self.screenCanvas.canvasy(event.y)

        self.rect = self.screenCanvas.create_rectangle(self.x, self.y, 1, 1, outline='red', width=3, fill="blue")

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        self.curX, self.curY = (event.x, event.y)
        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        self.screenCanvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, self.curX, self.curY)

    def recPosition(self):
        print(self.start_x)
        print(self.start_y)
        print(self.curX)
        print(self.curY)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Code is working with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Code is also working with

```
root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

But why not with this???

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
main()
```

Getting error from the class Application:

```
...root.attributes("-transparent", "blue")
NameError: name 'root' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because

```py
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

defines `root` in the local scope of the function, so when it is referenced in `Application` it causes the NameError.
to fix it try using `self.master` instead of `root` in the class

Comment: Okay, I uderstand this - this would be the way how I'd do it but now I'm not entirely sure why was it working without this modification? with only `root` in the Application class?

Comment: because `root` was global and it could be referenced from within the class

Answer (score 2):

What happens is that you are creating root in the function `main` namespace; it is therefore not accessible outside of it any longer.

You could do like this:

```
def main():
    global root    # this ensures you use the already created root from the `__main__` namespace
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = None
    main()
```

More finfo about [scope and namespaces](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say try

```
 def main():
  root = Tk()
  app = Application(root)
 root.mainloop()
    
  main()
```

Before you call the other 1 or 2.